# How can I check if my server have RAID-1?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, ubuntu-14.04, raid1

With `lsblk` command I get:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3    8:3    0 200.4G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 200.3G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3    8:19   0 200.4G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 200.3G  0 raid1 /
```

With `cat /proc/mdstat` get:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      209984640 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/2 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      33521664 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/proc/mdstat` output is very clear: you **are** using RAID1. You have three software RAID1 arrays, to be more precise.

Comment: Thank you. How can I check the free space of sda and the free space of sdb?

Comment: If you are referring to non-partitioned space inside your disks, from `lsbck` it seems that you have **no** free spece. If you mean the free space of your filesystem (on top of the RAID1 array), simply issue `df -h` and read the output.